# How to handle colons in command-line application user inputs?

Tags: swift, command-line, zsh

```
var name: String?
print("What is the name?")

if let input = readLine() {
    name = input
}

if let name = name {
    print("You input: \(name)")
}
```

I have a command-line application where the user is asked to input a name that may contain colons. In the macOS zsh terminal, when the user inputs a colon, it autocompletes to what looks like a dictionary:

```
acidgate % What is the name? // prompt user for input
acidgate % [Acid Gate: 2020] // the user's input is autocompleted with brackets
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
acidgate % What is the name?
acidgate % Acid Gate: 2020 // no autocomplete
```

If I can disable this autocomplete in my application, that would be ideal. If not, how do I handle the response? Because if the user manually deletes the brackets after they are autocompleted for him, the string has weird artifacting:

```
You input: Acid Gate: 2020� // printing the user's input
```

However, if the user doesn't remove the square brackets and inputs `[Acid Gate: 2020]`, the print console appears to show a clean string:

```
You input: Acid Gate: 2020
```

Comment: I have problems to reproduce your issue. When I run the program, no autocompletion takes place while reading with readLine().

Comment: Do you have `oh-my-zsh` installed? It may be that its `_swift` completion is kicking in.  Like Martin R., I'm unable to reproduce this.

Comment: @Gairfowl that is indeed the issue, good catch. You can post as an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `oh-my-zsh`'s completion scheme for `_swift` is being invoked.

You should be able to override the omz completion with a simpler version that doesn't recognize colons, e.g.:

```
compdef '_files -g "*"' swift
```

more here: https://superuser.com/questions/686267/disabling-oh-my-zsh-svn-completion